# How to access array of objects inside $scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to access an array of objects within $scope.
If I console.log($scope) (see image below) it displays the pedigree object that I would like to access. However, if I console.log($scope.pedigree) I get undefined.  If I  console.log(typeof $scope.pedigree) I get object.

Can someone help me access pedigree?

[image: firebug of scope]

Comment: can i show your web service response sample?

Comment: "if I console.log($scope.pedigree) I get undefined. If I console.log(typeof $scope.pedigree) I get object." - this should not be possible. Can you recreate the error in a plunkr? `console.log` is asynchronous, you're logging a reference to `$scope`, and `pedigree` might very well be populated later, asynchronously.

Comment: how you store value in $scope.pedigree? please give sample code

Answer (score 0):

Pedigree is an array of objects, not a single object.  As a result, you need to access the appropriate instance by index to get your object.

```
var pedigree = $scope.pedigree[0];
```

There is no "array" type in Javascript.  As a result, when you use `typeof` on your `$scope.pedigree` property, it will tell you it is of type object, even though happens to be an array of objects.

Comment: That's what I thought!  I get  undefined when 
        var pedigree = $scope.pedigree[0];
        console.log( pedigree);

Comment: @jparry do you also get undefined when you log `$scope.pedigree[0].id`?  If you cannot log it properly, please doldt's comment since you are probably trying to log the object before it has been hydrated.

Comment: Yeah still undefined.  I think doltd is on to something here.

Answer (score 0):

You can access to scope via jquery or jqlite: $('.element').scope();
Accessing via console.log is not possible, because angular doesn't use global scope for storing scopes. More information [here](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Understanding-Scopes).

Comment: why you think that OP do it not inside controller function or somewhere else where `$scope` is available?